# Unity3d: Want the cube to face the controller everytime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, virtual-reality, quaternions

[image]

So I have a controller and a cube, I want the cube at the right hand side of the controller, and need the cube to face the controller[image]

In Second picture, it isn't facing the controller

I don't get why it isn't rotating around y axis. It is at the right hand side of the controller though, but only the rotation is the problem

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    RightCube.transform.position = RightHandController.position + RightHandController.right * 2;

      RightCube.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(RightCube.rotation.x, RightHandController.rotation.z, RightCube.rotation.z);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you know the world location you want the RightCube's forward to face, you can just use [`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html):

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    RightCube.transform.position = RightHandController.position + RightHandController.right * 2;

    RightCube.transform.LookAt(RightHandController.position);
}
```